# Complex numbers modulus/argument question

Tags: complex-numbers

$z=\cos x+i\sin x$

Find the modulus and argument of:

$ \dfrac{1+z}{1-z} $

I wrote $z=e^{ix}$, so

$$\frac{1+z}{1-z}= \frac{1+e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}}= \frac{1+2e^{ix}+e^{2xi}}{1-e^{2xi}} = 
\frac{1+2(\cos x+i\sin x)+i\sin(2x)+\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(2x)-i\sin(2x)}$$
but then I'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $x=2y$ for better clarity of rendering

Dividing the numerator & the denominator by $e^{iy}\ne0$

$$\frac{1+e^{2iy}}{1-e^{2iy}}=-\dfrac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}$$

Now using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry),
$$\dfrac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}=\frac{2\cos y}{2i\sin y}=-i\cot y$$

Comment: Why a second answer that's identical to the other one?

Comment: @egreg, not sure about 'identical' as the other answer is based on Double Angle formulas and this one on Euler's formula

Comment: You're just using them implicitly.

Comment: I prefer this one, looks much more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Writing  $x=2y$ for better clarity of rendering

Using [Double Angle formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html)

$$\frac{1+\cos2y+i\sin2y}{1-(\cos2y+i\sin2y)}$$

$$=\frac{2\cos^2y+2i\sin y\cos y}{2\sin^2y-2i\sin y\cos y}$$

$$=\frac{2\cos y(\cos y+i\sin y)}{-2i\sin y(\cos y +i\sin y)}=i\cot y$$

---

Alternatively, the orthodox method for $\displaystyle\frac{a+ib}{c+id}$ is to rationalize the denominator as follows:

$\displaystyle\frac{a+ib}{c+id}=\frac{(a+ib)(c-id)}{(c+id)(c-id)}=\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}+i\frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2}$

$$\text{So, }\frac{1+\cos x+i\sin x}{1-(\cos x+i\sin x)}=\frac{1+\cos x+i\sin x}{1-\cos x-i\sin x}$$

$$=\frac{(1+\cos x+i\sin x)(1-\cos x+i\sin x)}{(1-\cos x-i\sin x)(1-\cos x+i\sin x)}$$

$$=\frac{(1+i\sin x)^2-(\cos x)^2}{(1-\cos x)^2+(\sin x)^2}$$

$$=\frac{1-\sin^2x+2i\sin x-\cos^2x}{1+\cos^2x+2\cos x+\sin^2x}$$

$$=0+i\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$$

Now apply Double Angle formula

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\frac{1+z}{1-z}=\frac{(1+z)(1-\overline z)}{|1-z|^2}=\frac{1-|z|^2+2\text{Im}(z)i}{|1-z|^2}=2\frac{\text{Im}(z)}{|1-z|^2}i$$

Comment: why does the $|1-z|^2$ disappear

Comment: It doesn't, @miracle173 :there it is. What disappeared is $\;1-|z|^2\;$ in the numerator since the given number has modulus one...

Comment: Yes, I now I see this. But then it is possible to simplify $|1-z|^2$ further.

Comment: It can be transformed to $$\frac{\text{Im}(z)}{1-\text{Re}(z)}i$$.